# Having trouble understanding Deeplinking

Tags: android, coinbase-api

I'm trying to implement the Coinbase Android Wallet SDK

In their tutorial on github

https://github.com/coinbase/wallet-mobile-sdk/tree/master/android

It tells me to use

```
CoinbaseWalletSDK(
    appContext = applicationContext,
    domain = Uri.parse("https://www.myappxyz.com"),
    openIntent = { intent -> launcher.launch(intent) }
)
```

Is the url inside `Uri.parse()` a server I would have to host myself?

I also checked coinbase's website and they provide users with a `Universal Link`

https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/wallet-sdk/docs/deep-link-into-dapp-browser

From the docs:

```
Universal Link 

https://go.cb-w.com/dapp?cb_url=[YOUR_URL]

YOUR_URL should be encoded with percent-encoding.
```

I'm confused because they provide us with a "Universal Link". Does that mean we just use their url or do we still have to host our own server?